# Lie bialgebras cohomology

Tags: homological-algebra, deformation-theory, poisson-geometry

I am wondering if there exist a universal construction of (co)-chain complex associated to a given algebra to study deformations as Hochschild homology for associative algebras, or Chevalley-Eilenberg cohomology for Lie algebras. 
I am interested in Lie bialgebras and their deformations. In particular, is it possible to use operads to construct a chain complex (as in simplicial homology)?

Comment: You should go to properads if you want to model bialgebras. A general theory that suffices for bialgebras is worked out in "Deformation theory of representations of prop(erad)s I and II" by Merkulov and Vallette.

Comment: I _believe_ that the case of Lie bialgebras was worked out earlier by hand in  Y. Kosmann-Schwarzbach, Grand crochet, crochets de Schouten et cohomologies d’algèbres de Lie, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. I Math. 312 (1991), no. 1, 123–126., but I haven't actually read it.

Comment: I agree with Gabriel's comments, but want to add one remark. There are different ways to model many-to-many operations: properads and props (which are essentially equivalent, by a deep result of Vallette's) allow compositions of arbitrary "genus" (or "loop order"); an alternate version, called "dioperads", uses only "tree-level" compositions. This in general makes a huge difference: the answers to homological-type questions can be very difference. I _think_ that for Lie bialgebras, you happen to get the same answers in the different settings, but for other types of bialgebras you often do not.

Comment: A very down to earth approach connecting to deformation theory is in my joint paper with L. Guerra "The variety of Lie bialgebras" http://www.emis.de/journals/JLT/vol.13_no.2/16.html